# Modify LDAP data given list of identifiers

Tags: linux, text-processing, ldap

I have a file with below content, where few lines are of length 15 while rest are less than 15.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
cccc
```

I need an output in below way.

Delete Subscriber:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

in

```
IMSI=AAAAAAAAAAAAA,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
```

Delete Subscriber: `BBBBBBBB`

```
MSISDN=BBBBBBBB,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
```

Delete Subscriber: `cccc`

```
MSISDN=cccc,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
```

Comment: Looks like LDAP output. Show us yout expected output please

Comment: I have shared above the way I require a expected output, Hope its visible. Please have a look friend

Comment: This is unclear what you asked, IMHO

Comment: Ok, I have a files with numbers in it. Now number length in the files varies from 8 to 15. for the numbers having length 15, i need below output
# Delete Subscriber: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

IMSI=AAAAAAAAAA,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te

While for numbers having length less than 15, I need below output

# Delete Subscriber: BBBBBBBBB

MSISDN=BBBBBBBBB,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te

Comment: You appear to have two different values for `dc=...` in your three example outputs, but you haven't explained what decides when the output should have `dc=imsi` and when the output should have `dc=msisdn`.  Would you please add this to your question?

Comment: Ok, Its the length of the numbers in the file.
when number length = 15 then dc=imsi, while for numbers shorter in length <15, it should give dc=msisdn

Comment: Hope my comment is clear above friends
I tried with this and it is working, but I am not able to make it through length

sed "s/.*/# Delete Subscriber: &\n\nIMSI=&,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te\n/" test_imsi.txt

Comment: Please help me out guys

Comment: I think it may be a bit unclear what the input and output of the operation should be. Do you want to _create_ a line saying `IMSI=AAAAAAAAAAAAA,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te` if the input is `AAAAAAAAAAAAA`, or do you want to _delete_ that line (or a part of it)? Showing variations of input of output would be helpful to understand what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello sorry for delayed reply, yes I have a input file with only numbers like AAAAAAAAA and BBBB in it (a sort of plain text file). The output should be like as described above, where the length of the digit in input file is =15 it should have dc=imsi line added while for those whose length is less than 15 digits, it should give the output having line dc=msisdn

Comment: Okay, elaborating it a bit more.
I have one file names test.txt, it contains numbers like (approx. 56 million in the original input file)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCC

Now using the input file above
eg length of AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA is 15 while BBBBBBBBB is 9, the output file should be like below

# Delete Subscriber: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

IMSI=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te

# Delete Subscriber: BBBBBBBBB

MSISDN=BBBBBBBBB,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te

Hope now the above thing makes it clear. Please support

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

You need a conditional statement:

```perl
~$ raku -ne ' if ($_.chars == 15) {print "IMSI=$_,dc=imsi,"} else {print "MSISDN=$_,dc=msisdn,"}; put "ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te";'  file
```

#OR

```perl
~$ raku -ne '($_.chars == 15) ?? print "IMSI=$_,dc=imsi," !! print "MSISDN=$_,dc=msisdn,"; put "ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te";'  file
```

Sample Input (adding 15-character `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` at top):

```
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
cccc
```

Sample Output:

```
IMSI=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
MSISDN=AAAAAAAAAAAAA,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
MSISDN=BBBBBBBB,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
MSISDN=cccc,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
```

One of the issues with the problem as stated is that the longest line given for the OP's Sample Input is only 13-characters. The code above gives a one-line return per one-line input. Raku's `-ne` "non-autoprinting command-line flags are used. The `$_` variable is Raku's (and Perl's) "topic variable". Raku's `print` statement doesn't add a terminating `\n` newline, while Raku's `put` statement does.

Modify output above as needed to add extra "Delete Subscriber" lines.

https://docs.raku.org/language/control#index-entry-control_flow_if-if
https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3F%3F%20!!
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample input provided in your question:

```
$ head file?
==> file1 <==
AAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
cccc

==> file2 <==
IMSI=AAAAAAAAAAAAA,dc=imsi,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
MSISDN=BBBBBBBB,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
MSISDN=cccc,dc=msisdn,ou=NPSD,serv=CSPS,ou=servCommonData,dc=te
```

If this isn't all you need, using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[=,]' 'NR==FNR{bad[$0]; next} !($2 in bad)' file1 file2
$
```

then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases where that doesn't work.